# Mac OS with TexMaker

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, texmaker, mac

I installed TexMaker latest (4.02 I think) on my MacBook, and got following message when trying to build a .tex file:

**Could not start the command.
"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex**

I have no idea what happened, and I also did not find much answer I need on internet. What is the problem? Could anyone help with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It could be that you have no `LaTeX` installation available (just the editor). One of such installations is TeXLive. If you do have it installed and from a terminal you can type `pdflatex` without getting a "not found" error, I recommend you clarify this in your question.

Comment: For Mac, [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) would be suited for you. Please look if you have it installed.

Comment: Are the paths set correctly in TeXMaker? The paths to the TeX binaries should be `/Library/TeX/texbin` not `/usr/local/texbin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TexMaker is an editor. You need a LaTeX distribution to compile the source files and produce the corresponding PDFs in your computer.

- The Latex project points to distributions for several operating systems: https://www.latex-project.org/get/
- The MacTex is a distro for Mac: http://www.tug.org/mactex/
- Depending on your installation, the latex programs (including `pdflatex`) will be in `/Library/TeX/texbin` or `/usr/texbin`

You may check more information at: [How to configure Texmaker to work on Mac with MacTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89028/how-to-configure-texmaker-to-work-on-mac-with-mactex) and [Texmaker on MacOS Sierra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338643/texmaker-on-macos-sierra)